# Spark read error file path does not exist

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

[image]

Hi Everyone,

While reading data from a file in spark I'm getting an error like path does not exist. Please find the screenshot for the same.

Could you please tell me what I missed regarding processing data?

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Regards,
Sunitha.

Comment: I think it should be `'file:///C:/work/datasets/us-500'` (two extra //).

Comment: Hi,Still i am getting same error. Path does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your data should contain path with file extension. It's missing here.

Add extension to `us-500`.